# org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have two tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "publicSitePortfolioWorks")
public class PublicSitePortfolioWorks implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "mainImage")
    private FrameworkFiles frameworkFilesByMainImage;
    @Column(name = "androidImage")
    private FrameworkFiles frameworkFilesByAndroidImage;
    @Column(name = "bigImage")
    private FrameworkFiles frameworkFilesByBigImage;
    @Column(name = "mainName")
    private String mainName;
    @Column(name = "androidName")
    private String androidName;
    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;
    @Column(name = "shortText")
    private String shortText;
    @Column(name = "`fullText`")
    private String fullText;
    @Column(name = "linkedObjectNameLocal")
    private String linkedObjectNameLocal;
    @Column(name = "`sort`")
    private Integer sort;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private Integer active;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "framework_files",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(
//                        table = "framework_files",
                        name = "linkedObjectName",
                        referencedColumnName = "linkedObjectNameLocal"),
                @JoinColumn(
//                        table = "framework_files",
                        name = "linkedObjectId",
                        referencedColumnName = "id"
                )
            }
//            , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "linkedObjectName")
    )
    private Set<FrameworkFiles> filesLocal = new HashSet<FrameworkFiles>(0);
```

And second table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "framework_files")
public class FrameworkFiles implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "fileName")
    private String fileName;
    @Column(name = "fileSize")
    private Float fileSize;
    @Column(name = "filePath")
    private String filePath;
    @Column(name = "fileUrl")
    private String fileUrl;
    @Column(name = "linkedObjectId")
    private Integer linkedObjectId;
    @Column(name = "linkedObjectName")
    private String linkedObjectName;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private Integer active;
    @Column(name = "uploadDate")
    private Date uploadDate;
    @Column(name = "uploadersIP")
    private String uploadersIp;
    @Column(name = "uploadersIPXFORWARDEDFOR")
    private String uploadersIpxforwardedfor;
    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;
```

When I have started my application, I got exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_hksv6kkf3cysf5ug30q575tg1:framework_files [filesLocal_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (framework_files [linkedObjectName,linkedObjectId,filesLocal_id])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:110)
```

Please advice, how to fix this exception.

I have seen many topics on stackoverflow about this Exception, but I can't understand, how to fix this error in my code.

Comment: You should have multiple variable for foreign key. it means you should have two variables for @JoinColumn

Comment: Hi. Can you explain with code example, based on my code? Thank you.